# Magento2 di in ResourceCollection

Tags: collection, magento-2.1.7, di

I have the  fallowing collection and I want to pass the ProductFactory so it can be accessible in my collection.

```
class Collection extends AbstractCollection
    {
        public $productFactory;

        /**
         * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface $entityFactory
         * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
         * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy
         * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager
         * @param \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface $connection
         * @param \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb $resource
         */
        public function __construct(
            \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface $entityFactory,
            \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
            \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy,
            \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager,
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface $connection = null,
            \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb $resource = null,
            ProductFactory $productFactory
        ) {
            parent::__construct($entityFactory, $logger, $fetchStrategy, $eventManager, $connection, $resource);
            $this->productFactory = $productFactory->create();
        }

        protected function _construct()
        {
            $this->_init(MyClass::class,MyResource::class);
        }
```

The error that I get is

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface in  

/var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php on line 73
```

What am I doing wrong, is the goal that I am trying to achieve possible ?

Answer (score 3):

For some reason I had to remove

```
\Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface $connection = null,
\Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb $resource = null,
```

from the **__construct()** completely. Removing

> = null

for both still didn't do the trick, removing them complete made everything work again.

The new **__construct()** looks like that:

```
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface $entityFactory,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy,
        \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager,
        ProductFactory $productFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct($entityFactory, $logger, $fetchStrategy, $eventManager);
        $this->productFactory = $productFactory->create();
    }
```

Solved.